# Modify request header to hide automatic testing flag

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to run automatic testing (using Selenium in C#) for a client's site, on which I do not have access to the back-end; however I keep getting the same "Access Denied" error when navigating to the site using Selenium ChromeDriver.

I have tried navigating to the site automatically and manually, and I get the error both ways, but it is working in a regular Chrome browser.

I think there must be a flag in the request header that is flagging the site that the session is being controlled by automatic software.

Is this correct, and is it possible to work around it?

Comment: You could use a tool like Fiddler (telerik) to intercept the http request coming from your selenium test and inspect the raw request. This will show any headers that it is sending. You can repeat the process with the stock Chrome browser and compare the difference. If it does relate to a header, you can even configure fiddler to intercept the request and manually manipulate it to test your theory. That will at least give you the answer to the first part of your question.

Comment: @AdamG any idea what I should be looking for in the raw request?

Comment: Confirmation or otherwise about your theory that there is a difference in the headers between the working request and the test which isn't.